# What other yoga scriptures has kak bushundi or bhushundi maharaj gifted to mankind?

Tags: scripture, upanishads, yoga-sutras, manuscripts, pranayama

Kak bushundi or bushunda maharaj or kagabujandar as he is referred to in south India has written yogic scriptures such as

1. Kagabujandar upanishad.
2. Kagabujandar pernum noel kaviyam 1000
3. Yoga vashista has a chapter dedicated to kagabujandar explaining his story and his method of yoga based on breath.

Is there any other manuscripts based on kagabujandar's yoga? Could anyone list them for me?

Respectfully yours.